# Ultimate Module Creator Image Helper very slow

Tags: image, helper, extensions

I used the [Ultimate Module Creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/) (UMC) to create a simple Admin interface for adding and editing a custom entity type in Magento. Three of the attributes are images, so UMC creates an abstract image helper and then an image helper that extends that which is specific to the entity type. You can see the source template for the class that it builds **[here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/blob/master/app/code/community/Ultimate/ModuleCreator/etc/source/app/code/Helper/Image/Abstract/010_content)**.

The problem is that, even though images are being saved to the cache, just calling `init()` in the helper takes about 0.5 seconds. This really adds up, and is slowing down any page where we use this custom helper.

The method in question is below:

```
/**
 * init image
 * @access public
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 * @param string $imageField
 *
 * @return MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Image_Abstract
 */
public function init(Varien_Object $object, $imageField = 'image') {
    $this->_imageProcessor = null;
    $this->_image          = $object->getDataUsingMethod($imageField);
    if (!$this->_image) {
        $this->_image = '/' . $this->_placeholder;
    }
    $this->_widht           = null;
    $this->_height          = null;
    $this->_scheduledResize = false;
    $this->_resized         = false;
    $this->_adaptiveResize  = 'center';

    try {
        $this->_getImageProcessor()->open($this->getImageBaseDir() . $this->_image);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_openError = $e->getMessage();
        try {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->open(Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->_placeholder));
            $this->_image = '/' . $this->_placeholder;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_openError .= "\n" . $e->getMessage();
            $this->_image = null;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is so slow? (Again, the whole class is linked to above.)

If not, can anyone suggest an alternative for use on the front-end? I am just assuming that `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` shouldn't be used (and may not be able to be used) for any non-Catalog image. Is that correct?

Comment: https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-resize-category-images/blob/master/app/code/community/Technooze/Timage/Helper/Data.php Most likely the resize is happening regardless upon each load.  This should give you some idea on how to implement a caching mechanisms to implement in the helper.

Comment: The abstract image helper was not done by the UMC author (that's me). I took it from a repo that does not exist anymore. if you look in the code you will find this url `https://github.com/wearefarm/magento-adaptive-resize/blob/master/README.md`. I don't know what the problem is, but I will investigate. In the mean time I have to close this issue because it's related to a third party extension. But you can post an issue on github so I won't forget about it. In the mean time, if someone wants to help, any PR is welcomed.